# Flickering on elements, Chrome only, with background-blend-mode only

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-blend-mode

We run the website www.desirio.com which uses a background-image on the body with

```
background-blend-mode: luminosity
```

In Chrome, when you hover over elements, you see strange white lines randomly blink "somewhere". When you remove bg-blend-mode (pay attention to remove it twice if you try it out with the debugger, as it's there in the CSS-rules twice on the body), flickering is gone.

It looks like this:

[image: screenshot of chrome flicker]

We are running Chrome 62 on OSX, but've seen it happen on other versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome troubles to apply the background-blend-mode on larger container such as

```
<body>
```

Take if off there and put it into your hero-section

```
.hero-section{
    background-blend-mode: luminosity;
}
```

Comment: but the hero-section isn't giving our body this effect, of course, as it's a much smaller container? So why should we "move" it there, it'll not have an effect at all and not the one we currently have for sure.